# Upgrading from SQLOLEDB to MSOLEDBSQL

Tags: sql-server, oledb

Trying to get a handle on upgrade implications. When I try and install the new `MSOLEDBSQL` driver, Windows says:

> A lower version of this product has been detected on your system.
>   Would you like to upgrade...

I am presuming that refers to the existing `SQLOLEDB` driver, and that updating will break my ability to use all of the applications that use `PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1`?
I'd like to use the new driver for the current project and moving forward, but wasn't planning to upgrade every application (and every user's installed driver, etc) just yet.

1. Is the new driver backward compatible without updating all the
   connection strings?
2. Can I roll back the old driver anytime? (I didn't see a download for
   it anywhere since it's deprecated.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am presuming that refers to the existing SQLOLEDB

That is not the case.

The installer is not trying to upgrade SQLOLEDB.  The old driver is part of Windows and won’t be affected by the installation or upgrade of MSOLEDBSQL.